# Django refuses to cascade on delete

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cascade

Django 1.9 with PostgreSQL.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class MyCrossModel(models.Model):
    one_thing = models.ForeignKey('OneThing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    other_thing = models.ForeignKey('OtherThing', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I go to delete one of these in the database, it cascade-deletes the one_thing, but does not cascade_delete the other_thing.

Scouring the Django docs but cannot find any mention of this behavior.

Comment: Any errors or just not cascading?

Comment: And also what do you mean "delete in the database"? These are not SQL level triggers. Just want to make sure

Comment: I think you have it backwards. If you delete `one_thing` or `other_thing` then the `MyCrossModel` instance will be deleted. You seem to be expecting it to work the other way around?

Comment: @morinx Sorry I mean I have an instance of a MyCrossModel and call the delete() method.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry The mystery then is why does the delete() on a MyCrossModel result in the deletion of the one_thing, but not the other_thing? What you describe is actually the behavior I expected after reading the docs, but it's a mystery why the one_thing is being included in the delete.